# How do I capture all the output from a CLI program?

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection

I need to capture all the messages from cmd.exe.

I tried `abc.exe &> res.dat`, but it doesn't seem to work with stderr or others. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Reconstruct your command like so:

```
abc.exe >res.dat 2>&1
```

This will send STDERR to the same location.

Comment: OP wants to capture all output from `cmd.exe` not `abc.exe` -- I think the difference matters.

Comment: What other messages will cmd output when he is running `abc.exe`? ...

Comment: Oh, I don't know, maybe `'abc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @martineau, that string is part of standard error and will be captured by my command, but thanks for playing.

Answer (score 2):

```
abc.exe 1>2> res.dat
```

also works.